# TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am working on a project using Nodejs and am trying to apply the password encryption but still getting this error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'email' of undefined". **please can anyone help me? THANKS**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/user');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
     done(null, user.id);
 });

 passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
     User.findById(id, function(err,user){
         done(err, user);
     });
 });

 passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
     usernameField: 'email',
     passwordField: 'password',
     passReqToCallback: true
 }, function(req, email, password, done){
     User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user){
         if(err){
             return done(err);
         }
         if(user){
             return done(null, false, {message: 'Email is already in use'});
         }
         var newUser = new User();
         newUser.local.email = email;
         newUser.local.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
         newUser.save(function(err, result){
             if(err){
                 return done(err);
             }
             return done(null, newUser);
         });
     });
 }));
```

Comment: `newUser.local` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

First, define `newUser.local` then `newUser.local.email` and `password`.

```
 var newUser = new User();
         newUser.local = {email:"", password:""};
         newUser.local.email = email;
         newUser.local.password = password;
         newUser.save(function(err, result){
             if(err){
                 return done(err);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

`local` is undefined. Try this:

```
var newUser = new User();
newUser.local = {
    email : email,
    password : newUser.encryptPassword(password)
}
```

Comment: It still didn't work, it now says: 'TypeError: newUser.encryptPassword is not a function'

Comment: Then `encryptPassword` is not a function. Can’t say anything about that without seeing the `User` class

Comment: `var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
    var userSchema = new Schema({
    email:{type:String, required:true},
    password:{type:String, required: true}
    });

    userSchema.methods.encryptPassowrd = function(password){
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(5), null);
    };
    userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
    };
       module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema); `

Comment: The method in Schema is called `encryptPassowrd` you call `encryptPassword` which doesn’t exist

Comment: Yes! Yes! Yes!!!  Thank you very much @iPirat, it works now.  the error was i used 'encryptPassowrd' instead of   'encryptPassword' like you rightly said.  Thanks Again.

Comment: @ChineduErnest - Please, consider to accept one of the answers if they have helped you.